# Issue Rendering Data using ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

The idea is to render data from the below JSON in the two following ways:

The expected outputs are

1. Display all i.e all the serial_number and name properties like

   0001 Mr.A
   0002 Mr.B
   0003 Mr.C
   0004 Mr.D and so on
2. Display only the grievance `properties`

   0001 Mr.A
   0002 Mr.B
   0005 Mr.E
   0006 Mr.F
   0009 Mr.I
   0010 Mr.J
   0013 Mr.M
   0014 Mr.N

This is the JSON(response) data:

```
[
    {
        "district": "Kolkata",
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "6",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0001",
                        "name" : "Mr.A"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0002",
                        "name" : "Mr.B"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0003",
                        "name" : "Mr.C"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0004",
                        "name" : "Mr.D"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ward": "7",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0005",
                        "name" : "Mr.E"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0006",
                        "name" : "Mr.F"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0007",
                        "name" : "Mr.G"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0008",
                        "name" : "Mr.H"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "district": "Hooghly",
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "8",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0009",
                        "name" : "Mr.I"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0010",
                        "name" : "Mr.J"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0011",
                        "name" : "Mr.K"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0012",
                        "name" : "Mr.L"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ward": "9",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0013",
                        "name" : "Mr.M"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0014",
                        "name" : "Mr.N"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0015",
                        "name" : "Mr.O"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0018",
                        "name" : "Bruno Fernandes"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the model class of the response received from making a GET API Call:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<User> userFromJson(String str) => List<User>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => User.fromJson(x)));
String userToJson(List<User> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class User {
  String? id;
  String? district;
  List<WardNo>? wardNo;

  User({this.id, this.district, this.wardNo});

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.id = json["_id"];
    this.district = json["district"];
    this.wardNo = json["ward_no"]==null ? null : (json["ward_no"] as List).map((e)=>WardNo.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["_id"] = this.id;
    data["district"] = this.district;
    if(this.wardNo != null)
      data["ward_no"] = this.wardNo?.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
    return data;
  }
}


class WardNo {
  String? ward;
  List<Grievance>? grievance;
  List<General>? general;

  WardNo({this.ward, this.grievance, this.general, this.urgent, this.services});

  WardNo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.ward = json["ward"];
    this.grievance = json["grievance"]==null ? null : (json["grievance"] as List).map((e)=>Grievance.fromJson(e)).toList();
    this.general = json["general"]==null ? null : (json["general"] as List).map((e)=>General.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["ward"] = this.ward;
    if(this.grievance != null)
      data["grievance"] = this.grievance?.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
    if(this.general != null)
      data["general"] = this.general?.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
    return data;
  }
}


class General {
  String? serialNumber;
  String? name;

  General({this.serialNumber, this.name});

  General.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.serialNumber = json["serial_number"];
    this.name = json["name"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["serial_number"] = this.serialNumber;
    data["name"] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}

class Grievance {
  String? serialNumber;
  String? name;

  Grievance({this.serialNumber, this.name});

  Grievance.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.serialNumber = json["serial_number"];
    this.name = json["name"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["serial_number"] = this.serialNumber;
    data["name"] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

The class that calls the API:

```
class ModelClass with ChangeNotifier {
  List<dynamic> _data = [];

  List<dynamic> get data {
    return [..._data];
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    final url = Uri.http('192.168.0.6:3007', '/fetchData');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(response);
    final List<User> users = userFromJson(response.body);
    print(users);
    _data = users;
    print(_data);
  }
}
```

The widget class where I want the data to be displayed:

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MainScreenState createState() => MainScreenState();
}

class MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  var clicked = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<ModelClass>(context, listen: false).getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void clickedButton() async {
    await Provider.of<ModelClass>(context, listen: false).getData();
    print('clicked');
    setState(() {
      clicked = !clicked;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<ModelClass>(context).data;

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Demo App"),
        ),
        body: !clicked
            ? Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Click Me'), onPressed: clickedButton))
            : ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(provider[0].wardNo[0].grievance[index].serialNumber), //*
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text(provider[0].wardNo[0].grievance[index].name)  //*
                    ],
                  ),
                  itemCount: provider[0].wardNo[0].grievance.length,

              ));
  }
}
```

Right now, the lines marked in the above widget renders the following output:
0001 Mr.A
0002 Mr.B
I would like to know what I need to do to render through the JSON in a way that would render the data exactly the way I stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code as you stated:
the boolean field `showGrievanceOnly` in MainScreen is used to denote if we want to show grievance data only or not.
This is User class:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<User> userFromJson(String str) => List<User>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => User.fromJson(x)));
String userToJson(List<User> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class User {
  String? id;
  String? district;
  List<WardNo>? wardNo;

  User({this.id, this.district, this.wardNo});

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.id = json["_id"];
    this.district = json["district"];
    this.wardNo = json["ward_no"]==null ? null : (json["ward_no"] as List).map((e)=>WardNo.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["_id"] = this.id;
    data["district"] = this.district;
    if(this.wardNo != null)
      data["ward_no"] = this.wardNo?.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
    return data;
  }
}


class WardNo {
  String? ward;
  List<Grievance>? grievance;
  List<General>? general;

  WardNo({this.ward, this.grievance, this.general});

  WardNo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.ward = json["ward"];
    this.grievance = json["grievance"]==null ? null : (json["grievance"] as List).map((e)=>Grievance.fromJson(e)).toList();
    this.general = json["general"]==null ? null : (json["general"] as List).map((e)=>General.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["ward"] = this.ward;
    if(this.grievance != null)
      data["grievance"] = this.grievance?.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
    if(this.general != null)
      data["general"] = this.general?.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
    return data;
  }
}


class General {
  String? serialNumber;
  String? name;

  General({this.serialNumber, this.name});

  General.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.serialNumber = json["serial_number"];
    this.name = json["name"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["serial_number"] = this.serialNumber;
    data["name"] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}

class Grievance {
  String? serialNumber;
  String? name;

  Grievance({this.serialNumber, this.name});

  Grievance.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.serialNumber = json["serial_number"];
    this.name = json["name"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["serial_number"] = this.serialNumber;
    data["name"] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

This is the ModelClass:

```
class ModelClass with ChangeNotifier {
      List<User> _data = [];
    
      List<User> get data {
        return _data;
      }
    
      Future<void> getData() async {
        final url = Uri.http('192.168.0.6:3007', '/fetchData');
        final response = await http.get(url);
        print(response);
        final List<User> users = userFromJson(response.body);
        print(users);
        _data = users;
        print(_data);
      }
    }
```

This is the widget MainScreen:

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MainScreenState createState() => MainScreenState();
}

class MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  var clicked = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<ModelClass>(context, listen: false).getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void clickedButton() async {
    await Provider.of<ModelClass>(context, listen: false).getData();
    print('clicked');
    setState(() {
      clicked = !clicked;
    });
  }

  ///this field is used to decide if we want to show grievance data only or not
  bool showGrievanceOnly = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<User> usersList = Provider.of<ModelClass>(context).data;

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo App"),
      ),
      body: !clicked
          ? Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Click Me'), onPressed: clickedButton))
          :
          // ListView.builder(
          //   itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
          //       Row(
          //         children: [
          //           Text(usersList[0].wardNo![0].grievance![index].serialNumber!), //*
          //           SizedBox(width: 10),
          //           Text(usersList[0].wardNo![0].grievance![index].name!)  //*
          //         ],
          //       ),
          //   itemCount: usersList[0].wardNo![0].grievance!.length,
          //
          // )

          ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
                children: [
                  if (usersList[index].wardNo != null) ...[
                    for (WardNo ward in usersList[index].wardNo!) ...[
                      if (ward.grievance != null) ...[
                        for (Grievance grievance in ward.grievance!) ...[
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(grievance.serialNumber ?? ''), //*
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Text(grievance.name ?? ''), //*
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ],
                      if (!showGrievanceOnly && ward.general != null) ...[
                        for (General general in ward.general!) ...[
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(general.serialNumber ?? ''), //*
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Text(general.name ?? ''), //*
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ],
                    ]
                  ]
                ],
              ),
              itemCount: usersList.length,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```